# Is the Sonar rule for Spring '"@RequestMapping" methods should be "public"' accurate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, sonarqube

There's a sonar rule for Spring that states: "@RequestMapping" methods should be "public"

And gives these examples:

```
@RequestMapping("/greet", method = GET)
private String greet(String greetee) {  // Noncompliant

@RequestMapping("/greet", method = GET)
public String greet(String greetee) {  // Compliant
```

These are the reasons given:

> marking a sensitive method private may seem like a good way to control how such code is called. Unfortunately, not all Spring frameworks ignore visibility in this way. For instance, if you've tried to control web access to your sensitive, private, @RequestMapping method by marking it @Secured ... it will still be called, whether or not the user is authorized to access it. That's because AOP proxies are not applied to non-public methods."

This seems reasonable for *private* methods, but does it really hold true for default (package-protected) visibility?

i.e.

```
@RequestMapping("/greet", method = GET)
String greet(String greetee) {
```

Source: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-3751

**edit**: just to clarify, I'm not asking if a *@RequestMapping* method has to be *public*, it doesn't. See [spring-restbucks](https://github.com/odrotbohm/spring-restbucks/blob/0ad584f6107f8fe3c8511b79825e9a0f3b830ff6/server/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/web/PaymentController.java#L73) for an example

I'm asking if declaring the method as *package-private* rather than *public* is really a vulnerability, as suggested by Sonar.

**edit 2**: I created a project here to try to demonstrate it: https://github.com/barrycommins/boot2-security

The tests show that the `@PreAuthorize` rules are applied to the controller method, even though it is package private.
Whether that should be the case, and whether it's reliable, I'm not sure.

Comment: Method annotated @RequestMapping may need to accessed by spring-mvc / spring-web jar  , hence they are needed to be public

Comment: Have you read the comment by the rule. It will work with a `private` modifier (and default for that matter) **only** if you don't apply AOP. As soon as you start using AOP (i.e . adding security by adding `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured`) it will not work and the security won't be applied (as a `private` method nor a `default` method can be proxied). Hence the advice to make it `public` then adding AOP will just work .

Comment: @M.Deinum This was the crux of my question really. I wasn't sure if this was really the case, because I seem to remember that CGLIB proxies could intercept non-public method.

That said, having looked through the Spring documentation again, it appears it might be possibly, but not recommended: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators

Comment: "Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within the target object are, by definition, not intercepted. For JDK proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be intercepted. With CGLIB, public and protected method calls on the proxy are intercepted (and even package-visible methods, if necessary). However, common interactions through proxies should always be designed through public signatures."

Comment: package default will only work if and only if the proxy is defined and created in the same package and is a class-based proxy. Else it won't work.

Comment: I've attempted to prove it here: https://github.com/barrycommins/boot2-security

It does appear to work, interestingly.
The call stack from the tests shows the CGLIB proxy intercepting the  call.

Comment: It does not work if the method is changed to private though, the aspect is not applied in that case.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it seems like the comments and the existing answer are trying to address the details, when that isn't really your question.

I'm going to make some assumptions, because I haven't investigated the details of this issue.  I'm just going to read into this what I see here.

In my opinion, the key thing the error message is trying to convey is that you shouldn't label something non-public if it actually isn't.  I think this is debatable, but that is what the error message is saying, again, in my opinion.

The entire point of adding a @RequestMapping annotation is to prepare that method for being called from outside the service.  In fact, it implies that the method is ONLY called from outside the service.  If you declare that method as package private, that presents a confusing intent.

On the other hand, I can now see an argument to mark methods with @RequestMapping as "private".  If the method will truly only ever be called from outside the service, and not from any application code (excluding framework code), how else could you express that except with "private"?

Comment: With this in mind, you could argue that an `@RequestMapping` method always has to be public as it will always be called from the outside. Be it through reflection but it is called from the outside nonetheless.

Comment: I was more trying to get at whether the Sonar rule was correct to call it a security vulnerability, suggesting that `@Secured` / `@PreAuthorize` won't work since the security aspect couldn't be applied to a non-public method.

You could certainly argue about the correct visibility from a java vs intent point of view, but at the moment I'm more interested in whether it's actually a vulnerability or not.

Comment: I would think that if the intent conveyed by your code is deceptive or diverges from actual reality, it is inherently a vulnerability.  However, whether something is truly a "vulnerability" or whether you can declare something to be "absolutely secure", can never truly be determined. It's all relative.